# Check memory usage of subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm developing an application in Python on Ubuntu and I'm running external binaries from within python using subprocess. Since these binaries are generated at run time and can go rogue, I need to keep a strict tab on the amount of memory footprint and runtime of these binaries. Is there someway I can limit or monitor the memory usage of these binary programs at runtime? I would really hate to use something like "ps" in subprocess for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a PID number of your subprocess you can read all info from [proc file-system](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/proc.5.html). Use:

> /proc/[PID]/smaps (since Linux
>   2.6.14)
>       This file shows memory consumption for each of the process's mappings.
>   For each of mappings there is a series
>   of lines as follows:

or

> /proc/[PID]/statm
>     Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages.

Alternatively you can limit resources which subprocess can aquire with :

```
subprocess.Popen('ulimit -v 1024; ls', shell=True)
```

When given virtual memory limit is reached process fails with out of memory.

Comment: I need to implement this from within Python. So I would need to fork a child process, and simultaneously run a while loop which keeps monitoring /proc/(pid)/smaps file. Isn't there some other way, ex: I can allocate fixed memory for a child subprocess? I was hoping to use python's memory manager somehow.

Comment: Dang, never thought of this. Yep, this should work just fine for me.

Comment: ulimit is obsolete. Excerpt from man page: "Warning: This routine is obsolete.  Use getrlimit(2), setrlimit(2), and sysconf(3) instead."

Answer (score 14):

You can use Python's [resource](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html) module to set limits before spawning your subprocess.

For monitoring, resource.getrusage() will give you summarized information over all your subprocesses; if you want to see per-subprocess information, you can do the /proc trick in that other comment (non-portable but effective), or layer a Python program in between every subprocess and figure out some communication (portable, ugly, mildly effective).