# Using Gekko opt package, is it possible to estimate how much memory will be required to solve a script?

Tags: gekko

I am using Gekko locally at a supercomputing center. I have a script that solves a MINLP which can scale easily to add more Mixed integer variables. I want to understand how expensive the computations will be as I increase the number of variables and how much memory I need to request.

I receive the following error when I request just 1 node at the size I'm currently working with:

```
Error: At line 461 of file custom.f90
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Operating system error: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

Memory allocation failed

Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
```

I can keep increasing the number of nodes, but if I run it largely overestimating the amount of memory, I have to pay for the extra unused memory allocation. Is there a function that can estimate the memory needed within the model builder?

Comment: I am not immediately aware of any way of doing this, but it may be worth considering adding this functionality. How big is the model you are working with? Is it hundreds or thousands of variables? Have you tried using intermediate variables to see if that lightens the load?

Comment: I am aiming for the model to work with thousands. I do have many intermediates in place to ensure the equation character limit of 15,000 isn't exceeded. So far, it works if I just increase the amount of memory allocated to the problem - sometimes it just takes a few tries in writing the batch code to make sure I'm not overestimating by too much.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a method to predict memory usage in Gekko but this may be an option to measure the use if you are in Linux: [Check memory usage of subprocess in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830658/check-memory-usage-of-subprocess-in-python)

Memory is allocated during the model build and during the solve. Additional memory is sometimes allocated during the solve based on the matrix factorizations. Each successive solve should use about the same amount of memory if you have small permutations of your problem.

You can limit some of the memory use with MAX_MEMORY:
https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmMaxMemory

```py
m.options.MAX_MEMORY = 3
```